# Rotina em Background para compilação de dados é uma boa ideia?

Tags: c#, mysql, node.js, cron, hangfire

A última empresa em que eu trabalhava tinha umas regras bem peculiares, estas não sendo tão comuns(até onde eu sei) em outras empresas de TI.
Basicamente a gente fazia a compilação de todos os dados que seriam usados nos gráficos do sistema.
Nessa compilação os dados eram agrupados por dia e por hora, e salvos em duas tabelas, uma sendo compilados_dia e outra compilados_hora.
A ideia de fazer isto era a seguinte, eu tenho vamos supor 1 milhão de registros de vendas na tabela de vendas, ao invés de carregar todos os 1 milhão de registros da tabela de vendas, eram carregados apenas os dados da tabela de compiled_daily, dessa forma havia uma substancial queda no número de registros que eram carregados. Como para o cliente, só é importante a forma que ele vai visualizar os dados, não importa como os dados do gráfico mensal foram montados.

Dando um exemplo mais claro, vamos supor que temos 100 mil registros na tabela de vendas neste mês.
Se eu pegar os dados da tabela bruta, vou ter que carregar 100 mil registros, se eu pegar os dados da tabela de dados compilados, serão apenas 30 registros, um pra cada dia, ai na compilação eu tenho a soma de todos os registros.

O que vocês acham, é uma boa ideia? Ou tem algum problema técnico com ela?

Comment: Nenhum problema se a solução é adequada às regras do negócio. Atualmente vários SGBD já dispõem de visões materializadas (Materialized Views) que atendem a este requisito, desde que o refresh não seja automático.

Comment: Você pode se aprofundar no assunto estudando BI, Data Warehouse e Cubos... tudo vai fazer mais sentido e talvez até tenha como aprimorar essa estratégia